# How to upload dsc.pfx file on Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate. Please help me to troubleshoot this problem so that I will be able to upload a digital signature pfx file. When I upload DSC the following information is displayed:

```
Java Plug-in 10.7.2.10
Using JRE version 1.7.0_07-b10 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\cavivek
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where/how/why are you trying to upload the PFX file?